# How to deploy laravel backend with nginx?

Tags: laravel, nginx

I had a spa project, frontend and backend are ran in different port.

I used laravel to build the backend, after finished the project I ran the commmand to start.

```
php artisan serve --port=3001
```

And nginx was like following:

```
# backend
server {
        listen 3000 default_server;
        listen [::]:3000 default_server;

        root /usr/nextJs/nextTestBackend/public;

        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;

                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
}
```

After that, **127.0.0.1:3000/api/GET/users** will turn into **127.0.0.1:3001/api/GET/users** then access my laravel backend.

Is this a great way to deploy backend with nginx? Or there is other way to do it?

I wonder know if it's okay that using **php artisan serve** on production?

Comment: On what OS do you want to deploy your code? Go to https://serversforhackers.com/?series=show and teach yourself. This question should not be on this SE.

Comment: @Kyslik Okay, I will check the website. I deploy my code at ubuntu, and I had tried different way at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52755141/how-to-run-laravel-backend-at-nginx-without-php-artisan-serve please have a look.

Comment: @Kyslik  Sorry dude, I edit my question. Can you have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52755141/how-to-fix-cors-on-nginx again?

Answer (score -1):

Is this a great way to deploy backend with nginx? yes it is, nginx is good choice
and this is a good tutor for u https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-laravel-application-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04
Or there is other way to do it? u can use apache

Comment: Is the okay that using php artisan serve on production?

Comment: @jimmy NO! Use php-fpm for that; see the serversforhackers.com site the guy there explains everything.