# How to fix CORS on Nginx?

Tags: php, laravel, nginx

I had a spa project which run frontend and backend using different port.

It can run successfully when I using **php artisan serve**.

But now I tried to run the laravel backend at nginx without **php artisan serve**.

```
# backend
server {
    listen 3000 default_server;
    listen [::]:3000 default_server;

    root /usr/nextJs/nextTestBackend/public;

    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }


    location ~ \.php$ { 
        try_files $uri /index.php =404;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        #fixes timeouts
        fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

After nginx start, **127.0.0.1:3000/api/GET/users** can't access laravel backend.

It will shows the error:

```
Failed to load http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/GET/test: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.
```

How to fix it? 
Even though I put this inside location{} it still get the same error.

```
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';
```

By the way the api at **laravel** also had CORS middleware.

```
Route::middleware('cors')->get('/GET/users', 'UserController@read');
```

Comment: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors read the manual to that. Also set proper trusted proxy, search that in the laravel documentation.

Comment: @Kyslik Hello, I run composer require barryvdh/laravel-cors and add Barryvdh\Cors\ServiceProvider::class and change the protected $proxies; into protected $proxies = '*'; But still get the same error. Anything I missing?

Comment: @hello i created chat room join here for solving your problem https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181669/how-to-fix-cors-in-nginx